# putting a source in bashrc file for root

Tags: terminal, root

I installed root. If I use in terminal, on mac: "source /Users/student/Downloads/root-6.04.14/bin/thisroot.sh" and then "root", the program works fine. But in a tutorial I watch they say that I can write "source /Users/student/Downloads/root-6.04.14/bin/thisroot.sh" in ~/.bashrc. And then I can just type "root" and it should work directly regardless the directory I am in. But it doesn't work. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the equivalent directory in mac, but for example, I'm using Ubuntu.

I have:

```
 test.sh
 chmod +x test.sh (to make it executable)
```

then, move it to /bin/ directory
Update ~/.bashrc file, put the code at the bottom part"

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

Finally,  you can run test.sh in any directory you're in.